# Usage of "convince A of B" and "convince oneself of~"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I want to know that I understand the usage of "convince A of B" and "convince oneself of~" correctly.

My father convinced me of my fault. = My father made me aware of my fault.

You need to convince yourself of your possibility. = You need to trust your possibility.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**convince someone of something** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/convince+of) an idiom

> to persuade someone that something is true. "You will never convince me
>   of what you say". "I will probably convince myself of the need to find a
>   better job".